# Does Spring Data's Cross-Store persistence support Document->JPA or Collections?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa

I'm evaluating a cross-store deign for a current project, where we're considering using both MySQL and MongoDB.

Independantly, the Spring support for each of these products is excellent.  However, the cross store support seems a litte more bleeding edge.

Having read the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.cross.store), I'm left with a few questions:

The doucmentation speaks of cross-store support for a JPA Entity which contains a property that is persisted as a `@Document`.  Does support exist going the other way?  Ie.,  Can I have a MongoDB document as the parent, which contains a reference to a JPA Entity (or a collection of entities)?

Eg:

```
 @Document
 public class Product
 {
      @Entity?
      private Manufacturer manufacturer;

      @CollectionOfEntities?
      private List<Review> reviews
 }
```

Similarly, is there support for persisting a JPA Entity which contains a collection of Docuemnts?

eg:

```
 @Entity
 public class Shop
 {
       @Id
       private Long id;
       // Product is a MongoDB @Document
       private List<Product> products;
 }
```

Is this supported?

Given that cross-store persistence is so new, are there any resources for design best practices, or pitfalls to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about cross-store.  But, EclipseLink (as of 2.4) supports JPA to both MySQL and MongoDB, and does support composite persistence units, that allow relationships across persistence units.